# Dual boot: Getting access to a partition made on both Linux and Window systems

Tags: permissions, partition, dual-boot

I have a Windows and Linux Dualboot and I made a partition of 200GB to store big files if needed. The problem is that from my Debian OS, I can't add folders or put new files in there. The partition is in /media/username/Partition. Anytime I want to open the partition in the folder program I have to put in my root password and even then I cannot add files to it. I have remounted it but doing that every time to get read/writing permission is a hassle. Also if I want to make a new folder, I get the error that the directory doesn't exist, although it does. On the Windows OS I can access it and use it no problem. Any help on how I can make it easy to use and access on Linux?

Comment: Is the partition NTFS?

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? Note that Windows turns it back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If internal drive partition better to mount in fstab, so automatically remounted on reboot. Copy example using UUID, but with your UUID. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: @ajgringo619 yea it was paritioned as NTFS. When using `df` I get type `fuseblk` and with `fdisk -l` I get type `Microsoft basic data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to make it work with an NTFS partition:

run the following to get the UUID of the partition:

`sudo blkid`

open the fstab file with:

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

scroll down and make an entry like so:

`UUID=D0C08198CC0839207   /media/user/HD     ntfs-3g permissions     0       1`

change the UUID and the mounting point to your use case. At the end it should have this structure:

`UUID=[The UUID of the partition]   [Mount point]     ntfs-3g permissions     0       1`

Save and reboot your computer. The partition should automatically be mounted with the permissions set in fstab.

Answer (score 0):

you're likely running into permission issues across the two different OS's and filesystems.  Depending on how secure this needs to be, you may be better served creating a partition with a filesystem that's "better" supported across both OS types (something like exFAT?)

Comment: What's wrong with NTFS?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" with it, but Linux and Windows don't always agree on things like what permissions mean what, the semantics of access control, etc.  You can't have {simplicity, capability, and interoperability} all at the same time - choose two.  ;-)  For interop and simplicity, having the "shared" partition be something like FAT32 instead of NTFS (which linux doesn't really speak) or ext4 (which windows definitely doesn't speak) helps.